# How to use prefixed route in blade?

Tags: controller, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have following routes:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/' , 'HomeController@index')->name('mainHomePage');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login' , 'admin\AdminController@login')->name('admin.login');
    Route::resource('/','admin\AdminController');
    Route::resource('subjects','admin\SubjectsController');
});
```

I'm unable to get the route of my subjects in blade syntax. I have working url `http://localhost/quizl/admin/subjects` .
But I get error when I try to get same route using `"{{route('admin.subjects')}}"` or `"{{route('admin.subjects.index')}}"` any where in **blade** file.
**UPDATE**
The error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'admin' (T_STRING), expecting
>   ',' or ')' (View:
>   /var/www/html/quizl/resources/views/admin/header.blade.php) (View:
>   /var/www/html/quizl/resources/views/admin/header.blade.php) (View:
>   /var/www/html/quizl/resources/views/admin/header.blade.php)
>   [image]

How to do this? I did not find much help in this context in internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time you can simply use whatever name you assigned to the route.  For example, `{{route('admin.login')}}`

However, when you group routes you have the option to "prefix the name" on all child routes like this:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/login' , 'AdminController@login');
    Route::resource('/','AdminController@index');
    Route::resource('/subjects','SubjectsController@subjects')->name('subjects');
}
```

Note the period after the name -- this will allow you to use dot notation to get the route named **subjects** from within the **admin group** like

```
{{route('admin.subjects)}}
```

The error in above code was simply `{{route('admin.subjects'))}}` was simply extra closing parenthesis.